# OpenVPN servername change broke my webserver

Tags: openvpn

I logged into my admin and changed the servername from an ip address to a vpn.myserver.org and now i cannot get to the admin user interface. It appears the webserver is not serving. I can still use openvpn from my devices so the service is running properly. I'm running on a Linode depian server and can't even figure out where openvpn is. It is not in /etc/openvpn

Can anyone give me some help? Is there a configuration file I can revert to get my admin back?

Comment: What does `service openvpn status` show?  What is the working directory from this command `cat /lib/systemd/system/openvpn.service`?

Answer (score 0):

My script placed openvpnas in /usr/local. The fix for my changing the hostname was to use this script

root@:/usr/local/openvpnas/scripts# ./sacli -k "host.name" --value "YOURNEW_VALUE" ConfigPut